# Add Service Reference for an optional string field doesn't generate "specified" field

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, web-services, wcf

I have an optional field of type string in xsd. when i update the service reference, this field changes to required.

for eg:

xsd:

```
 <xsd:element minOccurs=0 name="middleName" type="xsd:string"/>
```

after updating the service reference, my reference file only have

```
public string middleName
```

it doesn't have

```
public bool middleNameSpecified
```

so it changes to required.

is there a way to fix this?

Comment: What happens when the `middleName` is not specified? Also, what do you mean when you say it becomes "required". Finally, do you also have the same problem when you use "Add Service Reference"?

Comment: i am doing add service reference.

Comment: it works fine for other types. 
for eg:

Comment: If it's failing for "Add Service Reference" then don't say "Updating service reference" in the title.

Comment: Also, what do you mean "it works for other types"? And which other types? Do you mean value types like `int`? And you didn't answer my other questions.

Comment: <xsd:element minOccurs=0 name="isMarried" type="xsd:bool"/> gets generated as public bool isMarried and public bool isMarriedSpecified

Comment: it works for long. i get phoneSpecified for long. only for strings i don't get the 'Specified' field when i update it

Comment: That's how it's meant to work because those types don't have a concept of `null`. It doesn't work that way for reference types like `string`. In the case of a `string`, if the field is not specified, you will get a `null` value for `middleName`.

Comment: i tried Adding a new service reference and updating a service reference both. both were not generating specified field. that why the title is having 'update a service reference'

Comment: "Add" is simpler and you need to "Add" before you can "Update", so "Add" would have been better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "specified" fields are only generated for value types which have a `minOccurs="0"` in the schema. This is because these types do not have a concept of "null".

That is not the case for `string` and other reference types. If a string is not supplied, then it will be received as `null`. In order to indicate that a particular `string` is not being supplied, simply set it to `null`.

Note that the lack of a "specified" field does not mean that the string is required.